# Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete ClassBodyDeclarations error while importing @Test annotation of TestNG within Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, enums, testng-eclipse, testng-annotation-test

I am learning Selenium.. I have successfully installed Testng on my machine but unable to import @Test from Testng while writing the script.below is the error message.

```
@Test
```

Error:

```
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete ClassBodyDeclarations**
```

what does this `Enumbody` error indicates.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete ClassBodyDeclarations
```

...implies that eclipse detected a syntax error in your code.

Presumanbly, you have tried something in the similar lines:

```
public enum Foo;
```

which produces the error as:

```
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete ClassBodyDeclarations
```

Some more details about your usecase, program structure, eclipse version, syntax error recovery and reporting components of the Eclipse JVM would have helped us to analyze the error in a better way. However, this error:

[image: EnumBody to complete ClassBodyDeclarations]

signifies that an unusual *syntactic* error have misled the compiler's syntax error recovery module algorithm. Possibly, it's a bug within [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) within the **Enumerations** module which is handled in a different fashion than the other tokens which causes it to be recovered in a different way and hence shows up the syntax error.